# How to pass the shape argument to tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to perform inference on a loaded graph:

```
ds_graph = load_graph(model)
graph_input = ds_graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/input_node:0')
graph_seqlength = ds_graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/input_lengths:0')
graph_output = ds_graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/output_node:0')
```

The variables I am iterating over are

```
inp[i]
sl[i]
```

In the loop

```
for i in range(num):
    with tf.Session(graph=ds_graph) as sess:
        logits = sess.run(graph_output,feed_dict={graph_input:inp[i],graph_seqlength:sl[i]})
        logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits, dim=-1, name=None)
        logits = sess.run(logits)
        output_length=np.array([logits.shape[0]])
        tf_greedy_path, _ = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(logits,output_length,merge_repeated=True)
        tf_greedy_path = tf.convert_to_tensor([tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_tensor) for sparse_tensor in tf_greedy_path])
        greed_out = ndarray_to_text(sess.run(tf_greedy_path)[0][0])  

    return greed_out
```

I know that this segment keeps adding elements to the graph with each iteration.  But I am not sure how to specifically fix this.

My limited understanding tells me to create the graph elements outside of the loop:

```
logits = tf.nn.softmax(graph_output, dim=-1, name=None)
tf_greedy_path, _ = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(logits,output_length,merge_repeated=True)
tf_greedy_path = tf.convert_to_tensor([tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_tensor) for sparse_tensor in tf_greedy_path])

for i in range(num):
    with tf.Session(graph=ds_graph) as sess:
        sess.run(graph_output,feed_dict={graph_input:inp[i],graph_seqlength:sl[i]})
        sess.run(logits)
        output_length=np.array([logits.shape[0]])
        greed_out = ndarray_to_text(sess.run(tf_greedy_path)[0][0])
```

But I still need to deal with the fact that output_length is computed during the execution.  Unfortunately, `ctc_greedy_decoder` does not take `output_length` as a tensor.  Or I would have passed in `tf.shape(logits)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer without the whole code, but yes you are right you should add all your operations to the graph before entering into the loop. And nothing seems to prevent you from using the `tensor shape` of your `graph_output` tensor (btw keep in mind that there is no need for intermediate calls, just evaluate the tensor you're interested in, any intermediate tensor will be computed automatically):

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1, 2]) # graph_output has a dynamic shape
logits = tf.nn.softmax(graph_output, dim=-1, name=None)
tf_greedy_path, _ = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(logits,[graph_output.shape[0]],merge_repeated=True)
tf_greedy_path = tf.convert_to_tensor([tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_tensor) for sparse_tensor in tf_greedy_path])

for i in range(10):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(tf_greedy_path, feed_dict={graph_output:[[[1., 2.]], [[3., 4.]]]})))
```

Comment: The problem is that `ctc_greedy_decoder` does not take a list of tensors, it takes a list of `int32`.  I am trying to think of a way to infer the dynamic shape before constructing this part of the graph, which is annoying.

Comment: It does take a tensor or a list of tensors:
`shape_tensor =  tf.constant([1])
tf_greedy_path, _ = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(logits, shape_tensor, merge_repeated=True)` works fine.

Comment: You are defining the shape of the tensor with `tf.constant`.  In my situation, the dimensions of `graph_output` depends on the input dimension of what gets fed in (dynamic shape).  I get `graph_output.shape[0] -> ?` and `tf.shape(graph_output)[0] -> Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)`.

Comment: `tf.constant` is a tensor so it was just to illustrate the fact that `tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder` can take a tensor argument. Anyway, see my updated answer for an example with dynamic shape.

Comment: You helped me understand the problem, thanks a lot!  I was getting messed up on executing `sess.run()` on intermediate results.  I assumed if I ran `sess.run(logits)` then `sess.run(greedy_output)` that I would not have to use `feed_dict` for both.

Comment: Which brings me a quick question.  If I want to evaluate and save some intermediate result.  What is the best way to not have to execute the graph twice?  In other words, I want `sess.run(logits)` and `sess.run(greedy_output)` without having to compute `logits` twice.

Comment: Just do `l, g = sess.run([logits, greedy_output], ...)`